# what is the best way to show an additional div with content in all devices(ipad/iphone/android) but not in desktop browsers

Tags: jquery, mobile, mobile-browser

i have two div blocks in my code

```
1. <div class="for-devices">

    //some additional elements

   </div>

2. <div class="for-desktops">

     //some additional elements

   </div>
```

my question is what is the best way to show **.for-devices** div for devices and **.for-desktops** for desktops. If we access page from devices **.for-desktop** div should be removed and if we access page from desktops **.for-devices** should be removed.

Comment: Check the related question on the right.... you have your answer there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to detect a handheld device in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

```
var UserAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

function DetectDevice()
{
   if (UserAgent.search("ipad") > -1 || UserAgent.search("iphone") > -1 || UserAgent.search("android") > -1){
      // Code for above devices
   }
}

DetectDevice();
```